# What is the enchantment on the Arch-Mage robe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Why can't I disenchant the Arch-Mage robes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most Unique items that have a unique enchantment on them cannot be disenchanted, to stop people from adding overpowered enchantments to high level armor.

You can see [*here*](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archmage%27s_Robes#Archmage.27s_Robes) what the enchantment actually entails.

Answer (score 1):

The Archmage's Robes is [quest reward](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Archmage's_Robes) given to the player after they become the Archmage of The College of Winterhold.

You can't disenchant certain unique items and artifacts, this robe being one of them.